# How do i pass a parameter as a percentage in DOM in a element.setAttribute in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, setattribute

[better if viewed in img uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YcCY.jpg)

```
function create(R,A){
  var B=R; 
  var C=A;          

  // if i define a number e.g. 50% it works but when i 
  //pass a value it doesn't
  img.style.top = "B%";             
  img.style.left = "C%";// same with c
}
```

Comment: well, B and C are not numbers, try 1, or 2 ... etc - oh, I see now ... try `B + '%'` etc

Comment: When i do an alert on B and C, I get the desired values. How do i pass it to the attribute as a percentage value.

Comment: @JaromandaX: U da man ...Giggity..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
function create(R,A){    
img.style.top = R+"%";
//pass a value it doesn't.            
img.style.left = C+"%";
}
```

Also there is no need to create the variable unless you are modifying the parameters of the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function create(R,A){    
var B=R; 
var C=A;          

img.style.top = B + "%";            
img.style.left = C + "%";
}
```

Your code didn't work because you have passed "B%" for the style property which is not right. You should try B+ "%".